# Divs dinamicos a partir de los datos de un modelo

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Necesito crear una vista con razor, que con datos de un modelo, vaya generando dinámicamente diferentes DIVs dándoles un ID a cada uno de ellos, que me permita identificarlos al momento de que el usuario los selecciona mediante javascript.

Tengo un modelo que tiene una lista de pacientes, los cuales necesito presentar en pantalla.

Y tengo en una parte de la pantalla un foreach que itera en la lista de pacientes

```
@foreach (var paciente in Model)

{

   // aca tengo el div que identifica a 1 paciente

  <div class="item" id=model.PacienteId + "_id">

      <div class="titulo">model.NombrePaciente</div>

      <div class="titulo">model.edad</div>

  </div>

}
```

Esto a pesar que compila bien, y no da errores al momento de la ejecución, no me genera los divs con IDs diferentes.

Alguien sabe de qué forma se realiza esto?

Mi idea es poder después seleccionar los objetos en pantalla a través de un checkbox.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo utilice para un proyecto lo mismo con jQuery y funciona perfectamente. Si le añades un for puedes crear todos los divs que quieras...

```
jQuery("#div_precios" ).append('<div id="precio_' +  cantidad_precios +'"  class="precio_actividad">');
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la informacion, ya habia envontrado como hacerlo con javascript modificando el div de esta forma<div class="item" id="PacienteId_@paciente.CodigoPaciente"> pero voy a probar tambien lo que me comentas.